# Trigger does not show any output in my custom Integromat app

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I work with the trigger (not instant). I see in the console that API responds to me, but module output is empty, why?
I use the 'All' option when running it in the scenario.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the Communication config and the example of the response? There has to be something wrong with the processing of the response.